# Extract numbers from a string using Birt Scripting

Tags: java, javascript, regex, scripting, birt

I am developing a reporting application using BIRT.
The database field contains other characters with the numerical data.
I  needed to filter out all other unwanted characters and extract only the numerical data from the database field. I didn't  do  it at the query(It was not feasible with my requirements). I did it at the BIRT script. But the javascript regex part of following BIRT script is not working. (But the javascript regex is correct. I tested it in online javascript validating sites)
But with the BIRT script,  regex part is not working. How can I implement this BIRT script correctly?

```
if(BirtComp.like(row["fldDescription"],"%Plate Count%",true)){
var data = row["bbb"];
var num = 0;
try{
    num= parseFloat(data.match(/\d+/)[0]);//this is the regex part that is not working
    }
catch(err){
    num = row["bbb"];
}


if(num<=100){
    if(BirtComp.match(row["fldResult3"],"/^.*<.*/") ){
    1.4
    }else if(num==100){
    num
    }else{
    1.4
    }
}else{
num
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Regards,
Aruna

Answer (score 2):

Its been forever since I did BIRT, but I believe BIRT scripting is just a JavaScript interpreter for Java.  I am pretty sure you can create and use Java objects.  I think [this site](http://birtworld.blogspot.com/2005/11/using-embedded-java-objects-within.html) speaks to it some, but you should be able to Google it fairly easily.

Probably the best way would be to use the [Java Regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-frame.html) APIs.  It allows regular expression processing, but you could also just parse it by hand.